# drupal commerce: productgroup containing the images and text

Tags: commerce

I'm working on a website which sells products (*bolt 4M / bolt 5M / hinge 4cm / hinge 6cm /  hinge 8cm* / etc.).

I want to have my products grouped inside productgroups(*bolt / hinge* / etc.) and attach an image and description to the productgroup.

When a user visits the website, i want to show a list of the different productgroups (with image/text). After clicking on a productgroup,  only the productgroup is show with the text and image, but also an dropdown from which the customer can select the specific product from this productgroup.

I installed commerce and already added products, but i'm unsure how to continue.
I did some research on the subject, but all i can find is the prefilled list: examples are the size of t-shirt or the color. Since my products are more dynamic than the prefilled list and different for every productgroup i thik i cannot use this for my benefids.

Since this is such obvious behaviour i would like to know: 
1 - Is this a good approach
2 - Are some pointers/example which can help me started
3 - How should i make this productgroup

Greetings,

Eduard Witteveen

Comment: Are you sure that [documentation here](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations) and [discussion on their support forum](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/375/structuring-product-variants) are not covering your needs already? Also, I'm pretty sure you could simply use good old taxonomy for similar effect, if all you need is a neat listing and commerce way is not for you. Have you considered it?

Comment: I used taxonomy and the the second link: thank you very much